# Paginate issue with count in a query with group by

Tags: php, dql

Ok I usually use a pagination code that counts the total pages, like this

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tableName WHERE `ganador2` = '1'";
    $total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
    $total_pages = $total_pages[num];
```

then i call the data with this query for echo page contents.

```
// Get page data
    $query1 = "SELECT id,name,lastname,email,codigo, media, phone, Pcode, birth FROM $tableName  WHERE `ganador2` = '1' LIMIT $start, $limit ";
```

this last part is the Working code, ok,

Know im trying to use it with this querys, this count how many times the user has entered his email.

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS num,id,name,lastname,email,codigo, media, phone, Pcode, birth FROM usuarios GROUP BY email";
    $total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
    $total_pages = $total_pages[num];
```

and

```
// Get page data
    $query1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS top,id,name,lastname,email,codigo, media, phone, Pcode, birth FROM usuarios GROUP BY email ORDER BY top DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";
```

The problem is for pagination, its telling me the query just found (2 users) but thats not true, so my query its wrong.. How can i calculate the total pages in the first query, as the second query is working just fine.

thanks

Comment: I don't understand how your queries works.. Selecting count with fileds which are not grouped by at the same time ?

Comment: NB: mysql_* functions are deprecated You could use a single query (your 2nd one) and use mysql_num_rows http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the group by you are getting a count per email. you are getting the number of records that have the first email... I think this is what you want.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT email) AS num FROM usuarios;
```

Comment: Works like charm, need to wait 5 min to acept

Answer (score 0):

You are grouping by `email`, so the second `COUNT(*) as num` does not give you the total number of entries, but rather each row's `num` field contains the total number of users with the corresponding `email`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*) AS total
FROM
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT wp_users.ID)
    FROM wp_vgr_order
    INNER JOIN wp_users ON wp_vgr_order.author_id = wp_users.ID
    GROUP BY wp_users.ID) AS ROW_COUNT.
```

You can change your query in start (and end )

Answer (score 0):

Just use 1 query to acquire both your limited data for pagination and the total number of records that would be found without the limit: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows

The first query will give the data for the current page.

Then then the second query will simply be: `SELECT FOUND_ROWS();` and that gives the unlimited total found by the first query.

Answer (score 0):

//NOTE: *For Fixing the Total Count issue*

Step1:- Go to the given below path
**File path => `node_modules/@adonisjs/lucid/src/Database/MonkeyPatch.js`   =>   Line : 153**
replace this line

```js
const counts = await countByQuery.count('* as total')
```

with the code given below:

```js
const counts = await this.client
        .queryBuilder().count('* as total').from({ main:countByQuery.count('*') })
```